# ImportError: cannot import name 'compute_associations' from 'dython.nominal'

Tags: importerror

I just installed dython using pip install dython to use the tabsyndex. Here is the block of import

import pandas as pd
from tabsyndex import tabsyndex
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

and it always shows

ImportError: cannot import name 'compute_associations' from 'dython.nominal'

Are there any way to import compute associations?

So far I tried reinstalling dython, but it always show the same error.

Comment: are you sure you installed the correct version of dython? (dython==0.6.6) 
maybe try an older version of dython. I got it working with dython==0.5.1 currently installed

Answer (score 2):

I am by no means an expert on the matter, but i had the same problem. When i looked at the github package and found the function is appeared that it was not called 'compute_associations' but '_compute_associations'. Adding the underscore in the import statement seemed to work for me, but maybe someone with a bit more knowledge could explain the intricacies here.
[Here is an image of the function name as found on github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYKLJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://shakedzy.xyz/dython/modules/nominal/#compute_associations):

> `compute_associations` was deprecated and removed. Use `associations(compute_only=True)['corr']`